# Prevent access a file using the same constant

Tags: php, security

**I need to block the directly access to some php files**. Currently I ussing a constant to prevent this, but when I include the constant from the primary file and include again another php file the third file aren't taken the value of the constant.

Currently I'm running the script on XAMPP with php 7.3. Ordered as follows:

Project/

- index.php
- link.php
- inc/
  - classes.php
  - functions.php

**index.php**

```
define( '__PATH__', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' )
[...]
include ( 'link.php' );
```

---

**link.php**

```
if( ! defined('__PATH__') ) die('unatuhorized');
[...]
require( dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'inc/classes.php' );
```

*Output*

```
__PATH__ = bool true
```

---

**/inc/classes.php**

```
if( ! defined('__PATH__') ) die('unatuhorized');
```

*Output*

```
__PATH__ = Undefined constant __PATH__
```

*Expected*

```
__PATH__ = bool true/false
```

---

**I want to...**
Allow the access: to index.php
Block directly access to: link.php, inc/classes.php

Comment: None of the code you've included in your example would have any output at all, let alone "bool true". Please include the _exact_ code that causes this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for blocking direct access is define a constant on index.php then check if the constant is defined on the other files I do not want to give direct access to in my application.

index.php

```
define('MYAPP',1);
```

links.php (at the very top of the file)

```
if (!defined('MYAPP')) {
    die('Please use the front door.');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I alredy do this. The problem is when I include a third file. I define _path_ on index.php, then I include links.php, in links.php I check the constant (It's Ok) but when I include another file called from links.php the constant _path_ is undefinied to classes.php

Comment: The distinction between your question and my answer is that you are using "Magical" constants instead of just a regular defined constant. Have you tried just a constant and not '__PATH__'?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php